# What is the aircraft loss-rate from Nimitz-class aircraft carriers?

Tags: military, aircraft-carrier, us-navy

What is the aircraft loss-rate from Nimitz-class carriers?   That is, what proportion of sorties result in the loss of the aircraft for reasons other than enemy action?

I was prompted to ask this after the Russian carrier Kuznetsov lost two aircraft in the space of a couple of weeks.

Comment: @mins While I agree that this is military related, we have many military related aviation questions, including many well received [questions asked about aircraft carrier operations](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=aircraft+carrier). I also don't see military questions listed as off-topic in the help center.

Comment: @mins What if it were a question about statistics for runway excursions for one type of runway or operation vs another?

Comment: @JonathanWalters: It would be interesting. The OP should clarify and emphasize the possible difference of landing techniques, or carrier designs.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is asking directly related to launch and recovery, in transit the aircraft isn't any different from one that is land based. I'm thinking he is after recovery operations that result in a loss of airframe that wasn't because of damage sustained in combat. Basically pilot error in landing...

Comment: @RonBeyer You're reasoning makes sense, but your conclusion doesn't seem to follow. Aircraft can be lost in a number of ways without pilot error during landing. If he's asking about the number of aircraft lost on landing, then an edit would be in order.

Comment: Hi, thank you for all the above comments.  @Ron Beyer - I had a mind losses for all reasons other than enemy action, that is, accidents of all types.   Certainly I don't mean to restrict the question to pilot error only.   Reading reports of the Kuznetsov incidents, it appeared that both were related to problems with the arrestor gear.   If someone can indicate a breakdown of losses by cause or phase of operation, e.g. during takeoff, during landing, fuel exhaustion - that would be even better!

Comment: @Crosbie That may be difficult, as the US Military is not required (nor does it usually) release accident reports regarding its aircraft. The NTSB has a good database of commercial/private accident statistics and data, but I don't believe there is a good source of the information you are asking for. You'd probably have to rely on news reports. It isn't a bad question, but I don't believe there is a good way to get the breakdown/info you are looking for. Good luck though, hopefully somebody does have it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Naval Safety Center publishes some useful stats [here](http://www.public.navy.mil/navsafecen/Pages/statistics/aviation/av_stats_main.aspx).

[image: 02-06 navy class a rates]
[image: marines class a]
<sup>(Rates are per 100,000 flight hours per year. [Source.](http://www.public.navy.mil/NAVSAFECEN/Documents/statistics/StatsPrevYrs/AviationTables.pdf))</sup>

[image: fy17 chart 1 - flight]
[image: fy17 chart 2 - ground]
([Source](http://www.public.navy.mil/NAVSAFECEN/Documents/statistics/AviationClassAs.pdf#page=2).)

A few more details are available in the [summaries](http://www.public.navy.mil/NAVSAFECEN/Documents/statistics/AvSummaries.pdf). One example:
[image]

Other examples:

- E-2C: Electrical arcing at vapor cycle power receptacle led to aircraft fire in the hangar bay.
- A single F/A-18C crashed 6.6 miles northwest of Lakenheath, England. Event Cost \$72,000,000
- MV-22: While recovering to LPD, MV-22 landed short of spot 2, main landing gear in deck edge netting
- Engine fire leading to ejection. Event Cost \$71,000,000
- Two CH-53 helicopters crashed while on training flight. All 12 crewmembers deceased.
- AV-8B experience catastrophic engine failure during takeoff. Event Cost \$62,800,000
- AV-8B experienced loss of thrust, pilot ejected safely. Event Cost \$62,800,000
- 2xF/A-18F Collided during Air-to-Air training. 2 aircraft lost. No fatalities. Event Cost \$173,580,662
- EA-18G inflight engagement during night CV landing caused extensive damage to aircraft
- F/A-18 impacted ground during air show practice. Event Cost: \$75,400,000
- MH-60S crashed into James River while performing SAR training flight. Event cost: \$25,508,816
- KC130T EXPERIENCED HAIL DAMAGE WHILE PARKED ON THE RAMP AT PETERSON FLD, CO
  (KCOS)
- F/A-18C crash during night air-to-ground training mission. Event cost: \$76,500,000
- [snip]
- T-45C: ACUTE PHYSIOLOGICAL EPISODE RESULTS IN ACTIVATION OF THE EJECTION SEQUENCE BY CREw. Event Cost \$37,800,000
- A single T-45C impacted the ground at high energy. \$37,800,000
- [snip]
- Aircraft impacted a tree during low level training. Aircraft recovered safely.
- [snip]
- MV-22 ditched off Okinawa during NVD training mission. Event Cost \$80,600,000

[Class A mishap](http://www.public.navy.mil/NAVSAFECEN/Pages/statistics/mishap_def.aspx) definition:

> \$2,000,000 or more and/or aircraft destroyed [or] Fatality or permanent total disability

Just note that these are just Class A's. It doesn't include B's, C's, or D's. Some of these aren't carrier related.

On a completely unrelated note, notice the costs. Modern a/c are expensive (although not all that is flyaway cost).

Comment: The math in the bottom table doesn't work... dividing the mishaps into the flight hours doesn't give the rates listed. Something else, not shown, seems to be in play.